# CMD after Run from VBS

Tags: vbscript, cmd, robocopy

The error I am having is that vbs is not passing robocopy to cmd after it opens. I can see the CMD window open but it never passes the robocopy command. Please help!

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRUN = CreatObject("wscript.shell")

If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3\vlc.exe") Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3\vlc.exe")
    MsgBox "Already Installed", 48, "32bit Search"
    Set objFolder = Nothing

ElseIf objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3\vlc.exe") Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3\vlc.exe")
    MsgBox "Already Installed", 48, "64bit Search"
    Set objFolder = Nothing 

ElseIf objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\SAFARIMontageMediaPlayer.exe") Then 
       objRUN.run """CMD robocopy /E ""\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3"" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3""",1,true
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objshell = Nothing

ElseIf objFSO.FileExists("C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\SAFARIMontageMediaPlayer.exe") Then 
       objshell.Run """CMD robocopy /E ""\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3"" ""C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3""",1,true
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objshell = Nothing

Else MsgBox "VLC not installed properly", 16, "Failed"

End If
```

Comment: added /c after cmd with no change

Comment: I know for sure the robocopy command works but getting the vbs script to do it is something else. `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> robocopy "\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3" "C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SA
FARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3" /E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quoting the full cmd line. Only the executed command needs to be quoted

```
objshell.Run "CMD /c ""robocopy ""\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3"" ""C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3"" /e "" ",1,true
```

But it is better/easier to let `Run` method directly execute `robocopy`

```
objshell.Run  "robocopy ""\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3"" ""C:\Program Files\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3"" /e ",1,true
```

Comment: When I use your method I get an error where it does not continue after the spaces in the source and destination directory. Looks like the double quotes aren't doing their job.

Comment: <pre> C:\Users\dcamilo\Downloads>robocopy ""\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3"" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFAR
I Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3""/e

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, September 26, 2014 12:32:27 PM
   Source - \\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared\
     Dest - C:\Users\dcamilo\Downloads\Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3\

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:\Program" <code>

Comment: It was a combo of the quotes and `/C`. Thanks MC ND!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many double quotes at the beginning of your command lines. Change

```
objRUN.run """CMD ...
```

into

```
objRUN.run "CMD ...
```

Leave the rest of the lines as they are.

On a more general note: **NEVER** use global `On Error Resume Next` in your scripts. If for some reason you must use error handling, do it as locally as possible, put proper error handling routines in place, and disable error handling as soon as possible afterwards.

Comment: I typically don't do that globally but bit of code is being used in a software automation program that would crash if it was not allowed to continue error free.

Comment: @Jerzy How *exactly* did it "not work"? Try `cmd /k` instead of just `cmd`, so that the CMD window remains open. What output does it show?

Answer (score 0):

First, run this from a command prompt to make sure it works as expected:

```
robocopy /e "\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3"
```

If so, it just needs to be converted into a VBScript string. If the quotes get confusing, it may help to build it step by step. Instead of using quotes, I'll use `Chr(34)` to keep things simpler:

```
strCmd = "robocopy /e"
strCmd = strCmd & " "
strCmd = strCmd & Chr(34) & "\\JERZYBOYSERVER\Shared Folders\Landing\vlc-2.0.3" & Chr(34)
strCmd = strCmd & " "
strCmd = strCmd & Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAFARI Montage\SAFARI Montage Media Player\vlc-2.0.3" & Chr(34)
```

You may want to output the command at this point to make sure it matches up to your first statement. If you're using CSCRIPT, you can use `WScript.Echo` to output the command string to the console. If you're using WSCRIPT, you can use an `InputBox` to display the string so you can copy and paste it to a command prompt.

```
WScript.Echo strCmd
' or
InputBox "", "", strCmd
```

If it looks good, go ahead and run it.

```
objShell.Run strCmd, 1, True
```